Database created by cli not showing up on phpmyadmin
I created a database using CREATE DATABASE db7. And then I imported a sql file I had using mysql -u root -p db7 < dbsqlfile.sql. The import was successful, however it took some time. I can see the database and all the tables on terminal.
I started the XAMPP server on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Now at localhost/phpmyadmin, I'm not able to see db7 there. My user is root and it has all the privileges. Even on phpmyadmin's User accounts section, I can see root with all the privileges.
How do I solve this problem?
